# Flutter doesn't run for android: Waiting for observatory port to be available

Tags: android, flutter

I am using the flutter game template to build a game as flutter practice.
The game works without problem and is on the app store, but I can't seem to get it running on android.

`flutter run --verbose` gives the following error:

```
Waiting for observatory port to be available...
E/AndroidRuntime(18131): FATAL EXCEPTION: main...
```

I've done the usual: flutter clean, flutter repair cache, etc.
I also recreated the android folder using: `flutter create .`

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it working on android. The issue was that I had integrated AdMob into the app but I hadn't set it up correctly.

`flutter run --verbose` revealed the problem. I then followed the step-by-step instructions here and got it working:

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk